# Can I delete the SDL Tridion Default Groups?

Tags: tridion

I've assumed there was something unique or special about the default Tridion groups (e.g. Editor, Chief Editor, etc) because creating a new Publication seemed to get these groups automatically.

I actually see that new publications get all of the groups in its assigned parent upon creation, it's not necessarily because they're default groups.

**Can I delete these default groups? Aside from the out-of-the-box workflow options, any reason to leave these in Tridion from a programming or technical perspective?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to delete a predefined group -- you will always get an error saying as much.

I can't speak as to the reasons for this, but I imagine the fact that they are used for new Publications is at least part of the reason.

You are not required to actually use them, though.

Answer (score 5):

New Publications outside of an existing BluePrint will pick up the default rights from the default groups. If you don't need any out of the box settings, you should be OK deleting them (but I have never tried, so it may not be possible). In the database they have a special flag (IS_DEFAULT_GROUP).

I tend to use them for controlling rights, and make my other groups members of Authors,and Editors etc so that I get some basic rights out of the box for all publications.

Comment: Good point, I tried deleting `Interaction Manager` and get `It is not possible to delete a predefined group. Group: Interaction Manager.` Trying to delete a group I am using like `Editor` gets me `Item is in use Unable to delete Group (tcm:0-7-65568).` So it's likely not possible to remove the default groups, at least in the Content Manager Explorer. I'll use naming conventions and unselecting them to effectively ignore them instead.

Comment: Why not rename the default groups?

Comment: Renaming works for me and I'll suggest it for new setups and future projects. I was tempted to tell a customer that already has other non-default groups, "yeah, sure go ahead and delete those defaults," but wanted to check and test first.

Answer (score 3):

In the original design of R5 security it was possible to delete the predefined groups, and this was intentional. If you are getting a specific message telling you it is not possible, then this constraint must have been added later, presumably as code was re-written for 2011.

The thinking back in R5 was that the predefined groups would offer a good "out-of-the-box" experience, and save people some configuration. (And of course, it offered backwards compatibility with R4.) Other features echoed this: for example, if you create a publication in a blueprint, the Rights of predefined groups are cloned from the parent publication. For groups you've created yourself, this doesn't happen. After all - if you've chosen to go for a custom security set-up it's reasonable to expect you to customise everything yourself, right?

I  can't think of a good reason for preventing their deletion. Perhaps someone thought the "custom" approach was just too unfriendly, but I'm speculating. (Anyone know the real reason?)

Comment: "For groups you've created yourself, this [automatic predefined groups cloned] doesn't happen" -- I've heard this before, but I think at least in SDL Tridion 2011 creating a publication does clone non-default groups from the parent. Got an R5.3 box handy?